# IF statement Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code:

```
def Gradiente(grado):
   suma = 0
   for i in range(porcent):
       x1 = entrenamiento[i][0]
       x2 = entrenamiento[i][1]
       y = entrenamiento[i][2]
       h = 1 / (1 + math.exp(-(t0 + t1 * x1 + x2))

       if (grado == 1):
           suma = suma + (h - y)
       elif(grado == 2):
           suma = suma + (h - y) * x1 

   return suma / porcent
```

at the if, it keeps saying invalid syntax (at the ":"), is it wrong?

Comment: in python indentation matters

Comment: Missing closing `)` for this expression: `(1 + math.exp(-(t0 + t1 * x1 + x2))`

Comment: Indent all the code below `def Gradiente(grado):`

Comment: i know about identation is just when i paste the code, the correct answer is the missin ")" thanks all

Comment: @hcwhsa put the answer so i can give you the credits.

Comment: The lesson here is that if you see an error on a line that looks fine, especially a statement that opens a block, look for unbalanced parentheses on previous lines.  What happened here is that the open parenthesis meant it was still trying to continue the expression for h.  You can't have an if statement nested inside an assignment, so that is an error.  Your editor may be able to help you here too.

Comment: @Menticolcito You can accept paxdiablo's answer, it's perfectly okay.

Answer (score 3):

97.2% of all problems people have with Python involves incorrect indentation :-) In your original question, your indentation was incorrect and you need to indent it properly:

```
def Gradiente(grado):
    suma = 0
    for i in range(porcent):
        x1 = entrenamiento[i][0]
        x2 = entrenamiento[i][1]
        y = entrenamiento[i][2]
        h = 1 / (1 + math.exp(-(t0 + t1 * x1 + x2)))  # <-- fix

        if grado == 1:                                # <-- style
            suma = suma + (h - y)
        elif grado == 2:                              # <-- style
            suma = suma + (h - y) * x1 

    return suma / porcent
```

However, you've since made it clear that was a typo on your part when entering the question in which case it'll simply be the missing close-parenthesis on that large mathematical formula (which is also fixed in my code above).

One other change made is the removal of superfluous punctuation from the `if` statements. People who use them tend to come from a C (or similar language) background where they're necessary. Using them in Python usually just clutters the code unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

Indent everything one tab after line 1. Indentation matters in Python.